# How to update column based on another column in the same table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am quite new to this whole SQL thing and can not wrap my head around how to solve my problem. My table looks like this, primary key is `(id, name)`:

```
| bid |   name   |   value    |
|=====|==========|============|
|  1  | filename | foo        |
|  1  | mime     | text/plain |
|  2  | filename | bar        |
|  2  | mime     | image/png  |
```

Now I want to update every name to contain a suffix corresponding to the mime type, so that it looks like this in the end:

```
| bid |   name   |   value    |
|=====|==========|============|
|  1  | filename | foo.txt    |
|  1  | mime     | text/plain |
|  2  | filename | bar.png    |
|  2  | mime     | image/png  |
```

I have a script that gets mime <-> suffix association from /etc/mime.type so that part is covered. However I can not for the life of me construct the correct SQL update query.

Any help would be very much appreciated! Sorry if this is a duplicate I was not quite sure what I had to ask for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can use a correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set value = (value ||
                 (select (case when t2.value = 'text/plain' then '.txt'
                               when t2.value = 'image/png' then '.png'
                               else ''
                          end)
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and 
                        t2.name = 'mime'
                 )
                )
    where name = 'filename';
```